# Unable to load Array List of image URLs from Picasso using Recycler View Adapter. But directly able to load from Url string

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup, picasso

I'm using Jsoup to parse Manga images from a website and putting them into recycler view to display them, but images are unable to load.
webpage link for pasing manga image link here: https://mangaeffect.com/manga/strongest-abandoned-son-2/chapter-1/

**DisplayActivity.java**

'''

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    chTextView=findViewById(R.id.chapterTextView);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.displayImageRecyclerView);
    displayChapterAdapter = new DisplayChapterAdapter(displayChapterModelArrayList,DisplayActivity.this);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DisplayActivity.this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(displayChapterAdapter);

    DisplayTask displayTask = new DisplayTask();
    displayTask.execute();
}


public class DisplayTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        displayChapterModelArrayList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        super.onPostExecute(unused);
        displayChapterAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        chTextView.setText(chx);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String imgUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("contentUrl");

        try {
            Document data = Jsoup.connect(imgUrl).get();
            chx = data.select(".container > .row").select(".sidebar-hidden.col-sm-12.col-md-12.main-col")
                    .select("#chapter-heading").text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Document data = Jsoup.connect(imgUrl).get();
            Elements x = data.select(".reading-content").select(".page-break");
           String chapterSrc = data.select(".reading-content").select(".page-break").select("img").attr("data-src");
           Log.i("src: ",displayChapterModelArrayList.get(0).getImgUrl());
           displayChapterModelArrayList.add(new DisplayChapterModel(chapterSrc));
            for(Element i:x){
                String chapterSrc = i.select("img").attr("data-src");
                str.add((String)chapterSrc);
                displayChapterModelArrayList.add(new DisplayChapterModel(chapterSrc));
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

'''

**DisplayChapterModel.java**

'''

```
public DisplayChapterModel(String imgUrl) {
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
}

public String getImgUrl() {
    return imgUrl;
}

public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
}
```

'''

**DisplayChapterAdapter.java**
'''
ArrayList displayChapterModelArrayList;
Context context;

```
public DisplayChapterAdapter(ArrayList<DisplayChapterModel> displayChapterModelArrayList, Context context) {
    this.displayChapterModelArrayList = displayChapterModelArrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_image_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DisplayChapterModel displayChapterModel = displayChapterModelArrayList.get(position);
    String str =displayChapterModel.getImgUrl();
        Picasso.get().load(str).error(R.drawable.ic_baseline_image_24).into(holder.imgUrl);
        Log.i(" jdfgjkdf: ", str);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return displayChapterModelArrayList.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgUrl;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImageViewX);

    }
}
```

'''

**Output Images using direct link:**
like,
displayChapterModelArrayList.add(new DisplayChapterModel([a link]"https://mangaeffect.com/wp-content/uploads/WP-manga/data/manga_612dbbc700b22/10bbb81546c3c21c7c39ccf516a706a0/1.jpg"));

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1EYS.png

**Output Images with array list link:**
[2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFiJg.png

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the issue is that you're updating your local ArrayList when you get the data, but the one which you have passed onto the Adapter does not get updated.

So I'd suggest you instead add the following method to your adapter. Something like this

```java
public void addImages(ArrayList<DisplayChapterModel> imgList) {
   displayChapterModelArrayList.clear();
   displayChapterModelArrayList.addAll(imgList);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And in your activity you store your images in your local array and then `onPostExecute` do something like this

```java
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        super.onPostExecute(unused);
        displayChapterAdapter.addImages(displayChapterModelArrayList);
        chTextView.setText(chx);
    }
```